# Incorrect insertion of data from the dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel with data.

[image]

I wrote a code that allows me to filter data depending on the company.

```
Sub testProjectMl()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long, lastERowDest As Long
    Dim i As Long, arrA, dictKP As Object
    
    'Create a variable
    Dim dictKS
    Dim dictVT
    Dim dictAK
    Dim dictPP
 
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    firstRow = 8 'first row with data
 
    arrA = sh.Range("A" & firstRow & ":A" & lastRow).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
    Set dictKP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictKS = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictVT = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictPP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictAK = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 8 To lastRow
        If IsNumeric(.Range("H" & i)) And Trim(.Range("H" & i).Value) <> "" And .Range("H" & i).Value <> 0 And .Range("H" & i).Value > 7000 Then
            Select Case True
                Case .Range("A" & i).Value Like "KP*"
                dictKP.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                               sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
                Case .Range("A" & i).Value Like "KS*"
                dictKS.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                               sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
                Case .Range("A" & i).Value Like "VT*"
                dictVT.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                               sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
                Case .Range("A" & i).Value Like "PP*"
                dictPP.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                               sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
                Case .Range("A" & i).Value Like "AK*"
                dictAK.Add .Range("A" & i).Value, Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                               sh.Range(sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.Cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
            End Select
        End If
     Next i
    End With
    
    Sheets.Add.Name = "KP"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "KS"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "VT"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "PP"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "AK"
    
    Set shDestKp = Sheets("KP")
    Set shDestKs = Sheets("KS")
    Set shDestVt = Sheets("VT")
    Set shDestPp = Sheets("PP")
    Set shDestAk = Sheets("AK")
    
    For i = 0 To dictKP.Count - 1
    lastERowDest = shDestKp.Range("A" & shDestKp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If lastERowDest = 2 Then lastERowDest = 1
    dictKP.items()(i).Copy shDestKp.Range("A" & lastERowDest)
    shDestKp.Range("L" & lastERowDest).Value = "7000" ' insert a static franchise value
    shDestKp.Range("M" & lastERowDest).Value = "0.12" ' insert a static tarrif cost value
    shDestKp.Range("K" & lastERowDest).Copy ' copy the target format
    shDestKp.Range("L" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) 'paste format into cell
    shDestKp.Range("M" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    shDestKp.Range("N" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dictKS.Count - 1
    lastERowDest = shDestKs.Range("A" & shDestKs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If lastERowDest = 2 Then lastERowDest = 1
    dictKS.items()(i).Copy shDestKs.Range("A" & lastERowDest)
    shDestKs.Range("L" & lastERowDest).Value = "7000" ' insert a static franchise value
    shDestKs.Range("M" & lastERowDest).Value = "0.12" ' insert a static tarrif cost value
    shDestKs.Range("K" & lastERowDest).Copy ' copy the target format
    shDestKs.Range("L" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) 'paste format into cell
    shDestKs.Range("M" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    shDestKs.Range("N" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dictVT.Count - 1
    lastERowDest = shDestVt.Range("A" & shDestVt.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'If lastERowDest = 2 Then lastERowDest = 1
    dictVT.items()(i).Copy shDestVt.Range("A" & lastERowDest)
    shDestVt.Range("L" & lastERowDest).Value = "7000" ' insert a static franchise value
    shDestVt.Range("M" & lastERowDest).Value = "0.12" ' insert a static tarrif cost value
    shDestVt.Range("K" & lastERowDest).Copy ' copy the target format
    shDestVt.Range("L" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) 'paste format into cell
    shDestVt.Range("M" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    shDestVt.Range("N" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dictPP.Count - 1
    lastERowDest = shDestPp.Range("A" & shDestPp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If lastERowDest = 2 Then lastERowDest = 1
    dictPP.items()(i).Copy shDestPp.Range("A" & lastERowDest)
    shDestPp.Range("L" & lastERowDest).Value = "7000" ' insert a static franchise value
    shDestPp.Range("M" & lastERowDest).Value = "0.12" ' insert a static tarrif cost value
    shDestPp.Range("K" & lastERowDest).Copy ' copy the target format
    shDestPp.Range("L" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) 'paste format into cell
    shDestPp.Range("M" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    shDestPp.Range("N" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
    
    For i = 0 To dictAK.Count - 1
    lastERowDest = shDestAk.Range("A" & shDestAk.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If lastERowDest = 2 Then lastERowDest = 1
    dictAK.items()(i).Copy shDestAk.Range("A" & lastERowDest)
    shDestAk.Range("L" & lastERowDest).Value = "7000" ' insert a static franchise value
    shDestAk.Range("M" & lastERowDest).Value = "0.12" ' insert a static tarrif cost value
    shDestAk.Range("K" & lastERowDest).Copy ' copy the target format
    shDestAk.Range("L" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats) 'paste format into cell
    shDestAk.Range("M" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    shDestAk.Range("N" & lastERowDest).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

As you can see, depending on the value at the beginning of cell A, I adding the row in a certain dictionary. Then there is a cycle for each dictionary and inserting values into a specific sheets.

[image]

But I have a problem, for some reason the same line is entered in all the sheets when iterating through dictionaries.

For example (KS sheet):

[image]

This sheet should have the following value:
[image]

When Select Case and adding a row to the dictionary, the value in cell A is specified correctly and corresponds to a specific dictionary. BUT I don't understand why, when iterating through dictionaries, the same value from the dictKP dictionary is inserted.

Example what need in the end:
[image]

Comment: Check out how to create a "[mcve]". In the process of putting one together, you might even locate your issue, and if not, it will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I would suggest you to try describing **in words** which are your expectations from the above code. A picture showing how would you like to look the processed range will also help. Then, I suppose that more than one occurrence of each company should occur. If my supposition is correct, your example must include at least one case of such a company. Do you want making a `Union` of all occurrences for the same company? If so, your code does not load the dictionaries in a way to do that...

Comment: Will "WT00000225" and "WT00000225" be processed in the same dictionary key? Is the pattern "XX00000" followed by three digits common to all existing companies?

Comment: @FaneDuru I need to union all the rows whose values correspond to Select Case (If A.Value Like "AK*", Then add row to dictionary). Yes, "WT00000225" and "WT00000225" should be in the same dictionary - dictWt.  As for the pattern "XX00000" - there are always numbers after XX, and it may not be zeros. Example: XX1234567 - this is also possible. My task is to union the rows corresponding to a certain Select Case into one array, then insert them into a sheet corresponding to the first two letters at the beginning of .Range("A" & i).Value.

Comment: @FaneDuru I added a picture that shows an example of what needs to be done in the end for the VT\d+ pattern. As you can see, the main idea is that all the rows should be divided into sheets with the names of companies (the first two letters). Example: if there are two rows in the table with the number VT\d+, then we enter all two rows in a new sheet, the name of which should be VT. It is the same for the other numbers. In principle, what is now described in my Select Case suits me. Only one problem: the dictionary does not store values.

Comment: OK. If I remember well, I supplied a piece of code to process a similar range, but you missed its point: `firstRow` should be the one keeping the headers... I will prepare a much simpler piece of code, doing what I understood you need. But I would also like you to clarify the following issue: Are there companies starting with other pair of letters you want **excluding them from processing**?

Comment: @FaneDuru Regarding the headers: I just didn't copy them, but copied only the data rows. Regarding the headers: I just didn't copy them, but copied only the data lines. There are companies for exclusion, they are a set of letters and do not correspond to the pattern: ^[a-zA-Z]+\d+ Unfortunately, they are always different and I don't have an exact list. That's why I applied Select Case. Thank you.

Comment: In the meantime I posted an answer. It processes all existing companies. If you need to exclude some such companies you can place them in an array, in fact in a comma separated string ("BB,CC,FF" etc.) and the code will transform it in an array and process only companies having the name not starting with the two characters from the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try using the next code. It needs **only a single dictionary, creating keys based on the first two company name characters**. It will add new sheets based on the dictionary keys and clear the existing if they exist:

```
Sub testProjectMl()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, newSh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, firstRow As Long
 Dim i As Long, arrA, minVal As Double, dict As Object 

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 firstRow = 7   'the row where the headers exist
 minVal = 7000  'you can change it (if another limit would be necessary)...

 arrA = sh.Range("A" & firstRow & ":K" & lastRow).value
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 
 For i = 2 To UBound(arrA)  'iterate between the array rows:
    If IsNumeric(arrA(i, 8)) And Trim(arrA(i, 8)) <> "" And arrA(i, 8) <> 0 And arrA(i, 8) > minVal Then
        If Not dict.Exists(left(arrA(i, 1), 2)) Then
            dict.Add left(arrA(i, 1), 2), Union(sh.Range(sh.Range("A" & firstRow), sh.Range("K" & firstRow)), _
                                   sh.Range(sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
        Else
            Set dict(left(arrA(i, 1), 2)) = Union(dict(left(arrA(i, 1), 2)), _
                     sh.Range(sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "A"), sh.cells(i + firstRow - 1, "K")))
        End If
    End If
 Next i

 'drop the dictionary items content in the appropriate sheet (add it if not existing):
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'to make the code faster, when inserts sheet and copy ranges...
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    If Not sheetExists(CStr(dict.Keys()(i))) Then
        Set newSh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=sh) 'insert the sheet if it does not exist
        newSh.name = dict.Keys()(i)
    Else
        Set newSh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(dict.Keys()(i))'set the existing sheet and clear its content
        newSh.cells.ClearContents
    End If
    dict.items()(i).Copy newSh.Range("A1")               'copy the dictionary range
 Next i
End Sub

Function sheetExists(shName As String) As Boolean
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name = shName Then sheetExists = True: Exit Function
   Next ws
End Function
```